# How can i set post featured image as background of wordpress post title? Is there any plugin for that?

Tags: wordpress

I want to set featured image as title background of WordPress posts. It should be in the background of the page and visible only through the header and title part of the page.

Example:like this website: https://www.techquila.co.in/nvidia-vs-amd/

Comment: Please check the answer on this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115954/featured-image-as-background-image-on-pages

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, please come back with your code and explain what you have tried in the body of the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Single.php create a div wrapping your title and on that div add

```
<?php
   $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'full');
?>
<div style="background-image:<?php echo $featured_img_url; ?>">
  <h1>Your Title</h1>
</div>
```